# SharePoint 2010 Custom WCF Service - Windows and FBA Authentication

Tags: sharepoint-2010, forms-authentication, wcf-security, windows-authentication

I have **SharePoint 2010** configured for **Claims Based Authentication** with both **Windows** and **Forms Based Authentication (FBA)** for external users.  I also need to develop **custom WCF Services**.  The issue is that I want Windows credentials passed into the WCF Service(s); however, I cannot seem to get the Windows credentials passed into the services.  My custom WCF service appears to be using **Anonymous** authentication (which has to be enabled in IIS in order to display the FBA login screen).

The example I have tried to follow is found at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff521581.aspx.

The WCF service gets deployed to _vti_bin (ISAPI folder).

Here is the code for the .svc file

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" 
Service="MyCompany.CustomerPortal.SharePoint.UI.ISAPI.MyCompany.Services.LibraryManagers.LibraryUploader, $SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$" 
Factory="Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Services.MultipleBaseAddressBasicHttpBindingServiceHostFactory, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerRuntime, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"
CodeBehind="LibraryUploader.svc.cs" %>
```

Here is the code behind for the .svc file

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ILibraryUploader
{
    [OperationContract]
    string SiteName();    }

[BasicHttpBindingServiceMetadataExchangeEndpoint]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)]
public class LibraryUploader : ILibraryUploader
{
    //just try to return site title right now…
    public string SiteName()
    {
        WindowsIdentity identity = ServiceSecurityContext.Current.WindowsIdentity;

        ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(identity);

        return SPContext.Current.Web.Title;
    }
     }
```

The WCF test client I have just to test it out (WPF app) uses the following code to call the WCF service...

```
private void Button1Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
        binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly;
        binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Ntlm;

        EndpointAddress endpoint =
            new EndpointAddress(
                "http://dev.portal.data-image.local/_vti_bin/MyCompany.Services/LibraryManagers/LibraryUploader.svc");

        LibraryUploaderClient libraryUploader = new LibraryUploaderClient(binding, endpoint);
        libraryUploader.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel =
            System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;

        MessageBox.Show(libraryUploader.SiteName());
    }
```

I am somewhat inexperienced with IIS security settings/configurations when it comes to Claims and trying to use both Windows and FBA.  I am also inexperienced when it comes to WCF configurations for security.  I usually develop internal biz apps and let Visual Studio decide what to use because security is rarely a concern.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured out the answer.  The key is to create a web.config file and deploy in the same folder as the .svc file.  The web.config file needs to specify the binding to use "**wsHttpBinding**" instead of "**basicHttpBinding**".  I also removed the Factory attribute in the .svc declaration and the BasicHttpBindingServiceMetadataExchangeEndpoint attribute on the class.

Comment: could you post your full web.config file as a solution?  I'm running into a similar issue with WCF and 2010 claims based authentication.